# Limits, find a limit that exist in absolute value but not outside the absolute value.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let I be an open interval that contains the point c and let f be a function that is defined on I except possibly at the point c. Suppose that lim |f(x)| as x->c exists. Give an example to show that lim f(x) as x->c may not exist.

Not really sure of an example for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr} -1 & x < 0 \\ 1 & x > 0\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: So what's the limit of |f(x)| here? 0? then the lim f(x) DNE?

Comment: @Arnold What is $|f(x)|$ if $x \ne 0$?

Comment: Wouldn't you want x to be greater than or equal to 0 for one of the parts of the piecewise function?

Comment: @Arnold I just didn't define it at $0$, since there's no need to.